# About problem generating invoice via CRON on Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, invoice

Good afternoon

About problem generating invoice via CRON on Magento

I am having the following problem in Magento

In digital product testing

If I perform the action of generating the invoice manually in the Backend works, the product is released for download

If I execute the action of generating the invoice manually via module by the controller works, the product is released for download

If CRON performs the action of generating the invoice via module does not work, the product is not released for download

I have isolated the test module in

We see the images of the processes executed in

http://tentaculos-biz.umbler.net/low_resolution_2017-02-28_17-35-39.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Good evening

You can close this question to me.

Because I put the following command line that corrected this case

```
Mage::app()->loadArea('adminhtml');
```